# The verb for love at first sight (idiom or word)

Tags: single-word-requests, idiom-requests

The verb for love at first sight (idiom or word) that is loving or liking them **nearly instantly**.

Love at first sight is an experience and therefore a noun. I wonder if there's a verb **close to**, if not exactly, what that means

Example - The kid ____ every supermodel he saw that weekend.

Comment: Are you sure you're not confusing *love* with *lust*?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

To ***[fall for](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/fall-for):***

> - to be very attracted to someone and to start to love them.

- The kid fell for every supermodel...

(MacMillan Dictionary)

Comment: @NVZ It can take a moment or eternity to fall for someone. This doesn't address the "instantly" criteria.

Comment: @User1234567890 Well, contextually, "instantly" is usually implied.

Comment: I don't know, I instantly fall for pranks (i'm gullible) but in the context of love, it general takes me a few weeks to **start** to fall for someone.

Comment: Or just *fell in love with*

Comment: I feel like this is more often used for the epiphany of love one has after they've spent time with another. Nothing specific to love at first sight here.

Answer (score 26):

**To be smitten by someone** — [English at home](http://www.english-at-home.com/idioms/love-idioms/)

> to be in love with someone
>   *"I first met him at a party and from that evening on, I was smitten."*

**Steal someone's heart** — [TFD](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/steal+heart)

> *Fig.* to capture someone's affections; to cause someone to fall in love with oneself.
>   *"When I first met him, I knew he would steal my heart away. And he did."*

Comment: I'm sorry but how does this factor in the time aspect. Just like "fall for," this can also take time. Please make adjustments if possible.

Comment: @User1234567890 _To smite_ is to strike forcefully something. It's cognate to _smith_ and _smithy_, and evokes the hammer blows of a blacksmith on a piece of hot iron. I cannot conceive of a hammer blow that doesn't notionally take place instantaneously in time.

Comment: "smitten with" is more natural to me than "by" when talking about a person, but looks like there's plenty of examples of both out there.

Answer (score 26):

What about **"to be love-struck"**? [Wiktionary](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/love-struck#English)

The [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lovestruck) article gives some more information too:

> Being lovestruck means having mental and physical symptoms associated with falling in love: 'love-struck. It means to be hit by love... you are hit in your heart by the emotion of love'.

To be struck by something is normally rather instantaneous, maybe that is what you were looking for.

Also [**love-stricken**](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/love-stricken).

Answer (score 9):

[***Enraptured***](http://every%20supermodel%20he%20saw%20that%20weekend.)

The kid **was enraptured by** every supermodel he saw that weekend.

defined as filled with delight, the very feeling of love.  In every use I've seen, it happens in an instant and is overwhelming.

Answer (score 9):

How about **infatuated**?

The kid was **infatuated** by every supermodel he saw that weekend.Definition of

> infatuate
>
> transitive verb
>    1 :  to cause to be foolish :  deprive of sound judgment
>   2 :  to inspire with a foolish or extravagant love or admiration

[Source](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/infatuated)

Comment: Absolutely the best answer, IMO - in contemporary usage, "infatuation" generally represents a superficial or thoughtless attraction to someone.

Comment: I'd go with "infatuated with" rather than "infatuated by", but that may be personal preference.

Answer (score 7):

> The kid was very **taken with** supermodels...

[Taken with someone or something](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/taken+with) means:

> highly attracted to someone or something.

[McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs]

Comment: Hi, Jony. Long time and nice to see your user name again. I edited your post and please take a look and try to follow this format when you answer a question next time.

Comment: @Rathony Long time indeed. I have started working in a lab after sitting idle for 8 months at home. Busting my ass long hours, leaves me no time to even exercise. I just occasionally up vote a question or try to answer one. Perhaps that's why I forgot to follow the format :)

Answer (score 5):

The verb **fall** pairs with **in love** to mean going from not being in love to being in love. The precise verb you're looking for is a phrase in English: **to fall in love at first sight**.

This huge verb is intransitive. You'll need to combine it with the preposition **with** to introduce the person who is loved:

> The kid **fell in love at first sight with** every supermodel he saw that weekend.

This turns up [15,900 results](https://www.google.com/#tbm=bks&q=%22fell+in+love+at+first+sight%22) on Google Books.

Answer (score 4):

Try **take a shine to somebody**. See [definition](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/take-a-shine-to-sb) by Cambridge dictionary

> To like someone immediately 
>   or **nearly instantly**

The kid took a shine to every supermodel he saw that weekend.

Answer (score 3):

The kid was **twitterpated** with every supermodel he saw that weekend.

[Oxford Dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/twitterpated)

> ADJECTIVE
>
> Infatuated or obsessed:
>
> Gus is still hopelessly twitterpated by Lee
>
> smiling into each other’s eyes, a
>   seemingly twitterpated couple glided past

Comment: I'd just go with "infatuated".

Comment: This term [comes](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=twitterpated) from the 1942 Disney movie, Bambi. I've only heard it in reference to that movie. It's [on the rise](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=twitterpated&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctwitterpated%3B%2Cc0), but still nowhere near as popular as [fall in love](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=twitterpated%2Cfall+in+love&year_start=1800&year_end=2016&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctwitterpated%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfall%20in%20love%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: Not saying it's bad -- it's the first thing that popped into my head -- but I'm not certain the intended audience would know it off-hand, unless they happen to watch a lot of old Disney movies.

Answer (score 2):

To express **the immediacy of liking someone** or something, like the flipping of a coin, the OP could say, *flip for*

> The kid **flipped for** every supermodel he saw that weekend

> [**flip for someone**/something](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/flip-for)
>   *to immediately like someone or something very much*
>   <sub>MacMillan Dictionary</sub>
>
> 2. To react enthusiastically or passionately to someone or something:
>      *I flipped for the new bartender.*
>      <sub>[American Heritage Dictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/flip+for)</sub>

Literary example

> Watching the redhead in the next stall take her swing, Mickey was immediately entranced by her, and later wrote, “**I flipped for her**— her body, her backswing, even her little dog, a Maltese terrier named Pepy.”
>
> <sub>[*The Life and Times of Mickey Rooney*](http://The%20Life%20and%20Times%20of%20Mickey%20Rooney)</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Current vernacular should be considered: "crushed"  as in 
The kid 'Crushed on' every supermodel he saw that weekend

In this case "crush" implies a sudden, strong emotional whirlwind attachment.

Answer (score 2):

enthrall (v.) 
also enthral "to hold in mental or moral bondage," 1570s, from en- (1) "make, put in" + thrall (n.). Literal sense (1610s) is rare in English. Related: Enthralled; enthralling.

captivate (v.)
1520s, "to enthrall with charm," from Late Latin captivatus, past participle of captivare "to take, capture," from captivus (see captive). Literal sense (1550s) is rare or obsolete in English, which uses capture (q.v.). Latin captare "to take, hold" also had a transferred sense of "to entice, entrap, allure." Related: Captivated; captivating; captivatingly.

Answer (score 1):

[Head over heels](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/head+over+heels) is the idiom I've most often heard used to describe instant infatuation.

> often used with *fall* to describe the beginning of a relationship

I tend to hear this used regardless of reciprocation.

Answer (score 1):

I would not take the kid and love literally. ENAMORED would have the necessary figurative flair. According to [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/enamored):

> 1: to inflame with love —usually used in the passive with *of*
>
> 2: to cause to feel a strong or excessive interest or fascination —usually used in the passive with *of* or *with* <baseball fans enamored of statistics>